# Python NLTK: parse sentence using conjoint structure, getting into infinite recursion

Tags: python, nltk, context-free-grammar

I am asked to create **`two`** different parse tree for the following sentence:

```
foo while bar and baz
```

Based on these two constructions:

```
S-> S while S
S-> S and S
```

The two different trees I have are the following:

Tree A)

```
     S
   / | \
  P  U  S
  |    /|\
  W   P U P  
      |   |
      W   W
```

Here is the code for A:

```
import nltk

groucho_grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring ("""
S -> P U S | P U P
P -> W
U -> 'while' | 'and'
W -> 'foo'|'bar'|'baz'
""")

print(groucho_grammar)

sentence = "foo while bar and baz"

rd_parser = nltk.RecursiveDescentParser(groucho_grammar)
for tree in rd_parser.parse(sentence.split()):
    print(tree)
```

And the result for A:

```
(S (P (W foo)) (U while) (S (P (W bar)) (U and) (P (W baz))))
```

Tree B)

```
       S
     / | \
    S  U  P
  / | \    \
 P  U  P    W
 |     |
 W     W
```

Now for part B, I just modified the grammar to the following:

```
groucho_grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring ("""
S -> S U P | P U P
P -> W
U -> 'while' | 'and'
W -> 'foo'|'bar'|'baz'
""")
```

But I am getting infinite recursion error:

```
    if isinstance(index, (int, slice)):
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this rule: `S -> S U P | P U P`

By allowing S to begin with an instance of S, you allow this infinite recursion:

```
S -> S U P
S -> (S U P) U P
S -> ((S U P) U P) U P
S -> (((S U P) U P) U P) U P
```

This is called left recursion, and it is caused by a symbol expanding to itself, in this case S expanding to S.

From the [NLTK book, chapter 8](http://www.nltk.org/book_1ed/ch08.html#backtracks_index_term):

> Recursive descent parsing has three key shortcomings. **First,
>   left-recursive productions like NP -> NP PP send it into an infinite
>   loop.**

**A solution**

Luckily, you can simply change the parser you use to one that does not share the left-recursive Achilles heel. Simple change this:

```
rd_parser = nltk.RecursiveDescentParser(groucho_grammar)
```

to this:

```
rd_parser = nltk.parse.chart.BottomUpLeftCornerChartParser(groucho_grammar)
```

This way you make use of the left-recursive-resistant [BottomUpLeftCornerChartParser](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.parse.html#nltk.parse.chart.BottomUpLeftCornerChartParser)

**Further reading**

The left-recursive problem is well-known in automata theory. There are ways to make your grammar non-recursive, as explained in these links:

1. http://www.cs.engr.uky.edu/~lewis/essays/compilers/rec-des.html
2. http://www.umsl.edu/~kjs9rc/CS4890/presentation.pdf
3. http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/68869/naacl2k-proc-rev.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much. Thank you.